# Error "'un.fn.init' is null or not an object" - Internet Explorer 8 (IE8) - jQuery 1.11.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm cross browser testing a site in Internet Explorer 8 and getting `'un.fn.init' is null or not an object`. The specific line has the following:

`re=function un(e,t){return new un.fn.init(e,t)}`

I'm using jQuery 1.11.3, since it's supposed to run on ie8. The site is being compiled with gulp.js. The site is also using a number of different libraries to help ie8 work in the head:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/js/other/object-keys-polyfill.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/other/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/other/nwmatcher.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/other/selectivizr.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/other/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

and this in the footer:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src='/js/other/rem.js'></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This error breaks everything; does anyone have any ideas about how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

No such syntax exists in the jQuery library.

It looks like your code is scrambled or obfuscated using some kind of tool. Most of the time, old browsers will not support completely scrambled or obfuscated JS.